# What is the grammatical function of the infinitive 'to aid them' in the following sentence? 'He could do nothing to aid them.'

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, sentence, infinitives

I am aware that infinitives can serve as the subject of a sentence (as in 'To underestimate her would be foolish'), as the object of a sentence ('He likes to play basketball'), and as the predicative complement of a sentence ('My aim is to help you').

What is the grammatical function of the infinitive 'to aid them' in the sentence 'He could do nothing to aid them'?

Comment: Adjunct of purpose. "He could do nothing _**[in order]**_ to aid them."

Comment: @fev could you please explain how 'to aid them' is an adjunct of purpose?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)

Comment: @StuartF I am familiar with what an adjunct is. What I do not know, however, is why 'to aid them' functions as an adjunct of purpose in the above sentence. I can understand why 'to save money' in the sentence 'He walked to save money' is an adjunct of purpose (since it explains why he walked). It is difficult (at least to me) to apply the same logic to the above sentence. Maybe you could elaborate?

Comment: Call it an adjunct of something else than purpose, then, if you dislike the name. It's not a syntactic term, but a semantic one, which means it's vague and not easy to grasp, but sounds good if voiced authoritatively. Names are unimportant; what is important is noticing that the main predicate _do nothing_ is a negative, and that changes all the semantics and lots of the syntax. If you don't bother noticing negatives, why bother noticing anything else?

Comment: There's no infinitival in "talking to her". It's a gerund-participial clause.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @BillJ. I have amended my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation where the *to*-infinitival is a dependent of the noun *nothing* rather than an adjunct of purpose is likely here.

If it were an adjunct of purpose it would tell us why nothing would be done.

> He could do nothing.
>
> Why would he do nothing?
>
> To aid them.

However, the salient reading in this case is not that doing nothing would aid them, but that it is not possible for him to aid them by doing any of the things he can do.

A relative clause with the same sense could be substituted:

> He could do **nothing that would aid them**.

Compare:

> The students had **nothing to aid them with their work**.

Again, there are two possible interpretations:

1. If the *to*-infinitival above were an adjunct of purpose, the
   students would be doing the aiding. This is however unlikely
   as the simple fact of the students having nothing is not likely to
   help themselves or some other group get work done.
2. The salient interpretation takes the *to*-infinitival as a
   dependent of *nothing* so that there is nothing such that the
   students had this and that this could aid them (the students
   themselves or some other group) with their work. This is again the
   relative clause interpretation.

Further examples of infinitival relatives from CaGEL p1067:

> i She’s the ideal person [(for you) to confide in ___].
>
> ii I’ve found something interesting [(for us)to read ___].
>
> iii A systems analyst wouldn’t be such a bad thing [(for her) to be ___].
>
> iv That is not a very good way [(for him) to begin ___].
>
> **v You're not the first person [___to notice the mistake].**
>
> The relativised elements here are respectively complement of a stranded preposition, direct object, predicative complement, manner adjunct, and subject. Except in the latter case a subject can be optionally included, preceded by the subordinator for.

Answer (score 0):

CAGEL says about infintival clauses:

> In general, infinitival clauses functioning as adjunct of purpose can be preceded by ***in order*** and characteristically
> can be moved to front position:
>
> - He walked *[(in order) **to save money**]*. [purpose adjunct]
> - *[(In order) **to** save money,]* he walked. (p. 1222)

So you can see that ***in order*** can be omitted as it was in your sentence. And you can move your adjunct as well:

> - *[(In order) **to aid them***, he could do nothing.

Think of your sentence this way:

> He could do nothing ***in the purpose of helping them***.

He had this purpose, but could do nothing to fulfil it. You could also express it in this way:

> He wished there were somthing he could do *[(in order) **to aid them**]*.

or

> He wished he could do something *to aid them*.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, @fev.

Comment: I can't see any reference to infinitival clauses on p1221 of CaGEL (H&P) Are you referring to Quirk et al's Comprehensive?

Comment: @BillJ oops, it is actually 1222 (bottom), will edit! CaGEL for sure. I looked up in Quirk... Not much there... It's chapter 4.4.